# Prevent style in jQuery from being added

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexbox

I have an accordion coded and with my limited understanding of jQuery I am trying to modify it to prevent a click event from adding a display:none class to the last paragraph element which I need to also display. I'm not sure how the class is being added.

I have the layout styled with as it should with use of flexbox. In an effort to prevent this hiding the last paragraph block I want to show on toggle, I tried modifying the jQ with something like:

```
$("#para").css("display", "block");
```

which only partialy works and adds other issues. Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fun_bunch/6n8x1euc/#&togetherjs=ycmm0C4uDd

I'd like to find a real solution.

Comment: Do you really need the class `tab-content` on the last paragraph? I see that that para is not the part of 3rd tab's content.